# Run python file from java

Tags: java

I am trying to run a python script using runtime in java, but the command doesn't work, I got this error:

> Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Even i set the PATH variable with the executable python.

```
public void call(){

  String command= "python C:/Python27/lib2.py";       
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

}

PATH = "C:\Python27"
```

Comment: Can you run the command manually from command line? Can you please show us your `PATH`?

Comment: Make sure that python is in the PATH where you're running the build, or specify an absolute path to your python executable in the exec task. Then take a look at [this](https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java)

Comment: Yes, it works fine manually from command line, i already set the PATH, but the error still present

Comment: Try getting rid of 'python' and just executing the file

Comment: This might be a tokenizer problem. Could you try running `exec` with `new String[] { "python", "C:/Python27/lib2.py" }` as an argument?

Comment: thank u gays, the problem is resolved when i restart eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). The sample code shows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 File log = new File("log");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
 Process p = pb.start();
 assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
 assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
 assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

You could do `env.put("PATH", "c://python/bin");` or wherever your python installation may be found, to ensure that python is found in path.

Comment: the same problem can not run th program "python"